# Error al compilar y cargar le proyecto

Tags: android-studio

Al cargar el proyecto me da un error es cosa del gradle pero no se solucionarlo

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.

   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484.

     Searched in the following locations:

       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.1-6040484/aapt2-3.6.1-6040484.pom

       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.1-6040484/aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows.jar

     Required by:

         project :app



* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED in 4s

6 actionable tasks: 6 execute
```

d

Comment: Es posible que esto se resuelva aplicando `Toggle Offline Mode` en la configuración de Gradle. Está explicado en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60483387/5587982) con una imagen.

Comment: No eso ya lo he probado a dale al boton de toogle

Comment: ¿Y probaste hacer un `Clean Project` y luego un `Rebuild Project`? Si puedes pulsa en [edit]  y agrega tu `gradle` para revisarlo.

Answer (score 0):

La solucion en crear un nuevo proyecto y copiar la carpeta app porque el problema es que el gradle creo que es del año catapun el que trae el proyecto