# Como acceder al menu y corregir el error que da?

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un 3 en raya con un menu de aplicacion  y esta en pantalla completa, y no se como acceder al menu de aplicacion os dejo el codigo.

```
    public class TresEnRayaActivity extends Activity {
    private Button mBotonesTablero[];
    TresRaya mGame;
    TextView mensajeJuego;
    TextView MarcadorAndroid, MarcadorUsuario;
    TextView nivel;

    SoundPool soundPool;
    int iDRisas, iDVictoria, iDEmpate;

    static final int DIALOG_DIFICULTAD_ID = 0;
    static final int DIALOG_SALIR_ID = 1;
    static final int DIALOG_ABOUT_ID = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // quita la barra con el
        // titulo
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); // no deja que se
        // vea la barra
        // del reloj y
        // demas
        Log.d("TresEnRaya", "Método onCreate");
        inicia();

        mGame = new TresRaya();

        nivel.setText(R.string.nivelFacil); // Empiezo con facil
        comenzarNuevoJuego();
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // recuperamos en tablero del Bundle guardado al destruirse la
            // instancia anterior
            mGame.setTablero(savedInstanceState.getCharArray("tablero"));
            // Pintamos el tablero recuperado.
            recuperaJuego();
            // Mostramos los mensajes que hemos recuperado.
            mensajeJuego.setText(savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("mensaje"));
            MarcadorUsuario.setText(savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("marcadorusuario"));
            MarcadorAndroid.setText(savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("marcadorandroid"));
        }
    }

    private void inicia() {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mBotonesTablero = new Button[TresRaya.BOARD_SIZE];

        mBotonesTablero[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mBotonesTablero[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mBotonesTablero[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        mBotonesTablero[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        mBotonesTablero[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        mBotonesTablero[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        mBotonesTablero[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        mBotonesTablero[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        mBotonesTablero[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);

        mensajeJuego = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MensajeJuego);
        MarcadorAndroid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MarcadorAndroid);
        MarcadorUsuario = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MarcadorUsuario);
        nivel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextModo);

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        soundPool = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor risas = assetManager.openFd("Laugh.ogg");
            AssetFileDescriptor victoria = assetManager.openFd("Victory.ogg");
            AssetFileDescriptor empate = assetManager.openFd("Oops.ogg");

            iDRisas = soundPool.load(risas, 1);
            iDVictoria = soundPool.load(victoria, 1);
            iDEmpate = soundPool.load(empate, 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void recuperaJuego() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mBotonesTablero.length; i++) {
            if (mGame.getTablero()[i] == TresRaya.LIBRE) {
                mBotonesTablero[i].setText("");
                mBotonesTablero[i].setEnabled(true);
                mBotonesTablero[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(i));
            } else {
                setMovimiento(mGame.getTablero()[i], i);
            }
        }
    }

    /******************
 *     
 */
    private void comenzarNuevoJuego() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mBotonesTablero.length; i++) {
            mBotonesTablero[i].setText("");
            mBotonesTablero[i].setEnabled(true);
            mBotonesTablero[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(i));
        }
        mensajeJuego.setText("");
        mGame.nuevoJuego();

    }

    /********************
     * 
     * @param Marcador
     */
    private void victoriaMarcador(TextView Marcador) {
        String marcador = Marcador.getText().toString();
        int marcadorInt = Integer.parseInt(marcador) + 1;

        Marcador.setText(marcadorInt + "");
    }

    /****************
     * 
     * @param jugador
     * @param posicion
     */
    private void setMovimiento(char jugador, int posicion) {
        mGame.setMovimiento(jugador, posicion);
        mBotonesTablero[posicion].setEnabled(false);
        mBotonesTablero[posicion].setText(String.valueOf(jugador));

        if (jugador == TresRaya.JUGADOR)
            mBotonesTablero[posicion].setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 200, 0));
        else
            mBotonesTablero[posicion].setTextColor(Color.rgb(200, 0, 0));

    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nuevo_juego:
            comenzarNuevoJuego();
            return true;
        case R.id.ai_dificultad:
            showDialog(DIALOG_DIFICULTAD_ID);
            return true;
        case R.id.salir:
            showDialog(DIALOG_SALIR_ID);
            return true;
        case R.id.about:
            showDialog(DIALOG_ABOUT_ID);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DIFICULTAD_ID:
            builder.setTitle(R.string.dificultad_menu);
            final CharSequence[] niveles = { getResources().getString(R.string.dificultad_facil),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.dificultad_medio),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.dificultad_experto) };

            int seleccionado = 0;

            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(niveles, seleccionado,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            dialog.dismiss(); // Cierra dialogo y establece el
                                                // juego
                            switch (item) {
                            case 0:
                                mGame.setNivelFacil();
                                nivel.setText(R.string.nivelFacil);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                mGame.setNivelMedio();
                                nivel.setText(R.string.nivelMedio);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                mGame.setNivelExperto();
                                nivel.setText(R.string.nivelExperto);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
            dialog = builder.create();
            break;

        case DIALOG_SALIR_ID:
            builder.setMessage(R.string.abandonarPregunta).setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.si, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            TresEnRayaActivity.this.finish();// Finaliza la
                                                                // Actividad
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null);
            dialog = builder.create();
            break;

        case DIALOG_ABOUT_ID:
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about, null);
            builder.setView(layout);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            dialog = builder.create();
            break;
        }

        return dialog;
    }

    /*****************
  *    
  */
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("TresEnRaya", "Método onStart");
    }

    /*****************
  * 
  */
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("TresEnRaya", "Método onStop");
    }

    /*****************
 * 
 */
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("TresEnRaya", "Método onPause");
    }

    /*****************
     *     
     */
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("TresEnRaya", "Método onResume");
    }

    /*****************
     *     
     */
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.d("TresEnRaya", "Método onRestart");
    }

    /*****************
     *     
     */
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("TresEnRaya", "Método onDestroy");
    }

    /*******************
     * 
     * @author monte
     * 
     */
    private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        int location;

        public ButtonClickListener(int location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public void onClick(View view) {

            if ((mBotonesTablero[location].isEnabled()) & !mGame.esJuegoFinalizado()) {
                setMovimiento(TresRaya.JUGADOR, location);

                int ganador = mGame.buscarGanador();
                if (ganador == 0) {
                    mensajeJuego.setText("Turno de Android.");
                    int movimiento = mGame.getMovimientoAndroid();
                    setMovimiento(TresRaya.ANDROID, movimiento);
                    ganador = mGame.buscarGanador();
                }

                if (ganador != 0)
                    mGame.JuegoFinalizado();

                switch (ganador) {
                case 0:
                    mensajeJuego.setText(R.string.mensajeTurno);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    mensajeJuego.setText(R.string.mensajeEmpate);
                    soundPool.play(iDEmpate, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mensajeJuego.setText(R.string.mensajeGanaUsuario);
                    victoriaMarcador(MarcadorUsuario);
                    soundPool.play(iDVictoria, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mensajeJuego.setText(R.string.mensajeGanaAndroid);
                    victoriaMarcador(MarcadorAndroid);
                    soundPool.play(iDRisas, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        CharSequence mensaje = mensajeJuego.getText();
        CharSequence marcadorusuario = MarcadorUsuario.getText();
        CharSequence marcadorandroid = MarcadorAndroid.getText();
        inicia();
        recuperaJuego();
        mensajeJuego.setText(mensaje);
        MarcadorUsuario.setText(marcadorusuario);
        MarcadorAndroid.setText(marcadorandroid);
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putCharArray("tablero", mGame.getTablero());
        outState.putCharSequence("mensaje", mensajeJuego.getText());
        outState.putCharSequence("marcadorusuario", MarcadorUsuario.getText());
        outState.putCharSequence("marcadorandroid", MarcadorAndroid.getText());
    }
}
```

donde creo el menu me da un error no se si tiene importancia porque la app compila os dejo una captura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Oye, ¿resolviste [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336540/error-al-compilar-y-cargar-le-proyecto)? Si la has resuelto, no la elimines, la solución debería constar para que pueda ser útil a futuros usuarios con problemas parecidos. Ese es uno de los fundamentos de este sitio.

Comment: Bueno la reabro y pongo la solucion. La borre porque es un pego y no habia cts solo los mensaje contigo

Comment: ¿Qué es un *pego*?

Comment: la solucion es tan sencillo como crear otro proyecto y sustituir la carpeta app